# List of data in R

Tags: r

I manage data in three different classes - tbl_df, tbl, and data.frame - for some reasons.

What I try to do is to make a list of several data like belows:

```
data1 with tbl_df, tbl, and data.frame.
data2 with tbl_df, tbl, and data.frame.
data3 with tbl_df, tbl, and data.frame.

list[1] means data1
list[2] means data2
list[3] means data3
```

However, I was surprised to realised that it is too hard to find how to do this. I'd appreciate to have an answer for this. Thanks.

Comment: what is your input? what output do you want? Your question is not clear form the time being.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you coerce a `data.frame` to a `tbl_df` from `dplyr` package, the object receives two more class designations, namely `tbl_df` and `tbl`.

```
library(dplyr)
class(tbl_df(data.frame(x = runif(5), y = runif(5))))
[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
```

They are more or less the same as `data.frames`, with the little difference when it comes to printing. From `?tbl_df`:

> The main advantage to using a tbl_df over a regular data frame is the
>   printing: tbl objects only print a few rows and all the columns that
>   fit on one screen, describing the rest of it as text.

Bottom line is that you can use the object of class `tbl_df`, `tbl` and `data.frame` exactly like data.frame`.

If you mean to calculate mean of the whole data set, perhaps a better structure would be a `matrix`?

In any case, in the below example I calculate means of columns and store the result in a list. The example can be optimized using `sapply` and `lapply` functions.

```
library(dplyr)
data1 <- tbl_df(data.frame(x = runif(5), y = runif(5)))
data2 <- tbl_df(data.frame(x = runif(5), y = runif(5)))
data3 <- tbl_df(data.frame(x = runif(5), y = runif(5)))

list.of.dfs <- ls(pattern = "data")

list.of.means <- vector("list", 3)
names(list.of.means) <- list.of.dfs

for (i in list.of.dfs) {
  my.df <- get(i)
  list.of.means[[i]] <- colMeans(my.df)
}

> list.of.means
$data1
        x         y 
0.4895666 0.4219187 

$data2
        x         y 
0.4100487 0.2763898 

$data3
        x         y 
0.6123135 0.5033225
```

Comment: I don't fully agree with "Bottom line is that you can use the object of class tbl_df, tbl and data.frame exactly like data.frame.". Why? `tbl_df`s never simplify single column data.frames to atomic vectors whereas `data.frame`s do that by default and I consider that a major difference. Compare for example: `x <- tbl_df(iris); x[, 1]` with `iris[, 1]`.

Comment: I agree, the `drop = FALSE` default in `tbl_df` sometimes makes a difference.